# Sodity - Smart Contract

Tags: solidity

I'm writing a Lottery contract that's supposed to accept players, pick a winner and send the NFTs collected to the winner's address, then start over again.
After running npm run test, the first 5 tests are passing but the "sends NFT to the winner & resets the players array" test fails, with an error message.
Lottery Contract sends NFTs to the winner & resets the players array: Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM.
Anyone want to assist solving this Error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I am not familiar with Solidity but there is almost no chance that someone can answer your question without seeing the code for the smart contract and the code for your failing test.  You should post a [mcve] and also change the title of the question to refer to the problem or error you are having.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know that HashEx has a security subscription, it seems to me that in your case it is just right, besides, serious techies are behind the hashex, just look how the time comes.